# Microsoft Azure AD Filtering

Tags: php, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Currently have problem with filtering specific column which is "companyName". I have two company names that I want to filter but I am unable to get even one to work. Without adding companyName filter I am able to fetch successfully users by their givenName and surname.

Here is the normal version of URL:

```
https://graph.windows.net/myTenant/users?$filter=companyName eq 'Company Name' and (startswith(givenName,'MyFirstName') or startswith(surname,'MyLastName'))&api-version=1.6
```

And here is the encoded version of URL:

```
$beginURL = "https://graph.windows.net/".Settings::$appTenantDomainName."/users";

$feedURL = $beginURL.'?$filter=companyName%20eq%20'."'Company%20Name'".'%20and%20(startswith(givenName,'MyFirstName')%20or%20startswith(surname,'MyLastName'))&'.Settings::$apiVersion;
```

For some reason it's returning NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all properties of supported directory objects can be used in a filter expression. For information about filterable properties of supported types, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity

Or you can check this in [Azure AD Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/) like below:

[image]

Comment: This is true which is sad. Currently looping all users but before returning them to the user I'll just loop every user and return it if has correct CompanyName